# How to add local git project (http://xyz.git) to gitlab onprem offline server

Tags: git, gitlab

I have downloaded a git project from bitbucket and currently it is on my local laptop. Project has many commits and changes history.
I want to push this project to my On-premise GitLab server(no internet ). I want to maintain all the commit history. How this can be done ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new **blank** project on your Gitlab server.
(Make sure to **not** initialize your repository with README)

Now you can follow the explanation on Gitlab :
***Push an existing Git repository***

Then go in your cloned repository and remove the old origin (i.e. bitbucket one):

> git remote rename origin old-origin

add the url of your gitlab remote (you can find the url by clicking on "clone")

> git remote add origin git@gitlab...../url_to_project.git

push the code to new origin

> git push -u origin --all
> git push -u origin --tags

Comment: I have another concern. How to add bitbucket project changes on the gitlab after following the method you mentioned. I want to sync the bitbucket projects with gitlab repo.

Comment: The link to bitbucket is still active. You just add a new default origin. Try git pull old-origin master to sync master.